# Event stops bubbling to delegated events, when removing item with direct event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Experimenting with jquery events.

It seems that if I remove an item within its own event handler, it stops the event from bubbling to delegated events, but directly bound events still fire.

However if I remove it in a delegated event, the event propagates like I would expect.

Since I am not returning false or using stopPropagation(), I would have thought the other events would still fire regardless if they directly bound or delegated.

Does this make sense? Is this a bug with jQuery? Looking for an explanation of why it is behaving like this.

here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ahhgu1bb/

When you click the blue-point, the 'A UP ...' never appears in the console.

When you click the green-point it does.

And the code:

The html:

```
<div class="main-background">
    <div class="inner-area">
        <div class="blue-point"></div>
        <div class="green-point"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the javascript/jquery:

```
$('.main-background').on('mousedown', '.inner-area', function(e) {
   console.log('A DOWN - deletegated inner-area mouse down'); 
});

$('.main-background').on('mouseup', '.inner-area', function(e) {
   console.log('A UP - deletegated inner-area mouse up'); 
});

$('.main-background').on('mouseup', function(e) {
   console.log('B UP - direct inner-area mouse up'); 
});

$('.blue-point').on('mouseup', function(e) {
   console.log('C UP - direct point mouse up');
   $(this).remove();
});

$('.main-background').on('mouseup', '.green-point', function(e) {
   console.log('D UP - delegated point mouse up');
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: I clicked `.blue-point` and saw the log `C UP ...` and the same for `.green-point`, seems like the problem cant be reproduced!

Comment: did you see the "A UP ..."? When you click both points? I never see that when I click the blue-point.

Comment: oh I see, `A UP...` will never get fired because you assigned a function to `.blue-point` directly. if you check the target of the event it would be `.blue-point` so the `.inner-area` is not the target and the event will not be triggered. remember if you assign an event to a child element, the delegated event of the parent will not be triggered on click of the child element! it's just good sense! if it was otherwise, it would be such a mess!

Comment: But if I remove the `$(this).remove()` in the `.blue-point` event handler, `A UP` does show up. This makes me think that removing it, is interfering somehow.

Comment: yes but if you see the order of the logs it is `C UP...` and then `A UP...` so unless the target of the event for the `.inner-area` (which is `.blue-point`) is present at the bubbling time (after the `.blue-point` event is triggered), there is no target for the `.inner-area` event therefore it will not be triggered.

Comment: I feel like we're close! But in the example, `B UP` does show when `.blue-point` is clicked. So I would think that the mouseup event for `.main-background' would have triggered also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

For delegated events:

> ... The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

So it seems that if I am using event delegation, the event is not actually directly bound to the attached element and is only triggered from bubbling up from the target element.

So in my case, since the target element was removed before bubbling was started, the bubbling does not happen (kudos to Amin Jafari!), and so the delegated events never fire. But any event handlers that were directly bound are triggered.